# Meteor how to create new MongoDB collection on a fly?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am new to mongo and js. Why when I create new collection it's not visible until I add something to it?

```
let sipdata = Mongo.Collection.get('users_sipdata');
    if (sipdata === undefined) {
        sipdata = new Mongo.Collection('users_sipdata');
    }
    const sip = sipdata.findOne({ isUsed: '0' });
    if (sip === undefined) {
        throw new Meteor.Error('error-action-not-allowed', 'There is no available SIP data',
            { method: 'Accounts.onCreateUser' });
    }
```

[DB before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sItAp.jpg)

After I insert some data:

```
let sipdata = Mongo.Collection.get('users_sipdata');
    if (sipdata === undefined) {
        sipdata = new Mongo.Collection('users_sipdata').insert({ somedata: 0 });
    }
    const sip = sipdata.findOne({ isUsed: '0' });
    if (sip === undefined) {
        throw new Meteor.Error('error-action-not-allowed', 'There is no available SIP data',
            { method: 'Accounts.onCreateUser' });
    }
```

[DB after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z36jO.jpg)

I need to check if collection exist -> find data else create empty collection. Could someone help with this?

Comment: You shouldn't need to create a collection explicitly unless you need special options line collation.  It will be created automatically the first time you insert a document into it, and if you query a collection that doesn't exist, it looks the same as a collection that exists but doesn't have any documents.

Comment: Thus, you can force-init a collection using insert and immediately remove a document. Note that you need to Meteor.bindEnvironment the surrounding function if this happens on the server outside of any Fiber scope.